# Creating a and calling a SQL Server Business Tools Report from asp.net/c# web page

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

I am attempting to run a report from an asp.net web page utilizing SQL Server Business Tools. There are plenty of tutorials on how to make a report and I have completed that step. I just don't know how to call it and apply filters from my .asp.net page. Is there a special Control?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have downloaded SQL Server Business Tools.

Does anyone know of an tutorial on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I continued to work on this problem and if anyone ever needs it, here is the solution. 
[‎12/‎28/‎2016 10:37 AM] Brannan Cass: 
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/26/tutorials/4606/getting-started-with-ssrs-part-8-show-ssrs-report-in-aspnet-web-page.aspx